# get coordinate of clicked points on Processing 3

Tags: processing

What I want to do is simply change the color of pixels I've clicked. So there are two states ;

mouse clicked

mouse not clicked

I'm using code below ;

```java
boolean myBol = false ;
void setup(){
  size(860,640);
  background(0);
}
void draw(){
  if (mousePressed) {

   if(myBol == true){myBol = false;} else {myBol = true;}

  } 

  if (myBol == true){
    stroke(255);
  point(mouseX,mouseY);
}}
```

When I run this code after first click it keeps drawing where ever I move the mouse but what I want is ; "draw everytime I click on screen". 
[image]

Comment: You're not showing all your code. Where does `clickx`, `clicky`, and `mousePressed` get their values from?

Comment: well sorry about that clikcx and clicky are just not used yet I will delete them. mousePressed is a boolean in Processing 3 I'm not populating it.

Comment: You have a condition that switch the state of myBol on click. So click again an that will stop the drawing, click again to draw so more, ... You just need to check `if(mousPressed) draw ...   I don't see the need to myBol here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check condition are not correct.

```
if (mousePressed) {
   if(myBol == true){
       myBol = false;
   } else {
       myBol = true;
   }
}
```

or basicly

```
if (mousePressed)
    myBol = !myBol
```

Will change the `myBol` value on each click.

Since you want to draw on click, no need of this value. Just use the mousePressed value directly

```
if (mousePressed) {
    stroke(255);
    point(mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got extra logic that doesn't make a ton of sense. Why do you need `myBol` when you already have the `mousePressed` variable? Couldn't you just simplify your logic to this:

```java
void setup() {
  size(860, 640);
  background(0);
}

void draw() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    stroke(255);
    point(mouseX, mouseY);
  }
}
```

Or you could use the mouse event functions, like this:

```
void setup() {
  size(860, 640);
  background(0);
}

void mousePressed() {
  stroke(255);
  point(mouseX, mouseY);
}

void mouseDragged() {
  stroke(255);
  point(mouseX, mouseY);
}

void draw() {
}
```

Also, `boolean` values can be used directly and with operators, so this:

```
boolean example;
if(example == true){example= false;} else {example= true;}
```

Can be shortened to just this, using the **not** operator:

```
boolean example;
example = !example;
```

And this:

```
if(example == true)
```

Can be shortened to this:

```
if(example)
```